# What happens under the hood when an USB drive is inserted?

Tags: 12.04, automount, udev

Some systems use udev / pmount to automatically mount thumbdrives. How is that solved in Ubuntu (specifically, Ubuntu 12.04)? Apparently, neither the pmount package nor the corresponding udev rules are present, yet Ubuntu mounts the inserted USB drives automatically. How does that happen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Ubuntu 12.04 (Unity, and presumably Gnome Shell/Classic) automounting is handled by GNOME Desktop/Nautilus, which monitors DBus events for insertion, etc. The `gvfs*` backend is used, in co-operation with `udisks` for the low-level mounting, etc.

`gvfs-mount` is used internally, and running it in monitor mode with the `-o` switch will show, for example:

```
$ gvfs-mount -o

Monitoring events. Press Ctrl+C to quit.
Drive connected:    'usb Flashdisk'
Volume added:       'DISK_IMG'
Volume changed:     'DISK_IMG'
Mount added: 'DISK_IMG'
Volume changed:     'DISK_IMG'
Mount changed: 'DISK_IMG'
Mount removed: 'DISK_IMG'
Volume changed:     'DISK_IMG'
Drive disconnected: 'usb Flashdisk'
Volume removed:     'DISK_IMG'
```

Comment: When I opened this post there was no answer. In the 4 minutes I was getting that link, you answered.

Comment: No problem, that's happened to me many times too - sometimes it will alert "1 new answer", other times you only see it after you've answered :)

Comment: [@izx](http://askubuntu.com/users/58612/izx): +1 nice answer! Do you also know a method to re-trigger USB automount process after you dismount the drive manually? Personally, I always use `pmount`, and most people simply unplug and replug the USB cable. I think that a single command able to reproduce the Ubuntu automount process would be greatly appreciated by everybody...

Answer (score 2):

GNOME deals with it. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB.

Answer (score 0):

mount:

```
/usr/bin/gvfs-mount --device=/dev/sdd1
```

unmount/eject:

```
/usr/bin/gvfs-mount --eject /media/$USER/disk
```